# JSON values including spaces

Tags: jquery, json

I've got JSON file looking similar to this:

```
"value1":{
    "zasob": "mln",
    "title": "siarki",
    "zasoby": [ 1,2, 3, 4 ],
    "wydob": "mln",                                 
     "wydobycie":   [ 8, 6, 5]
    },
```

and when I change value of "title" to sometext that including spaces for example

```
"title": "soli sawss"
```

then trying to access this file with $.getJSON cant be done. But when I remove spaces everything back to normal. How can I solve this?

EDIT[SOLVE]:

there were few commas missing between nodes. I validated my file at [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com) and then everything was OK.

thanks guys!

Comment: It might be a copy-paste problem, but you do need those commas at the end of the lines...

Comment: JSONLint.com (http://jsonlint.com/) should help.

Comment: if it's not very long, it could help to see the complete json content

Comment: thank you it wasnt problem with spaces. ;)

Answer (score 0):

as long as your string is in double quote and you have the comma at the end, it shouldn't be a problem ...may be you should post the whole json with replaced string